# Visual Studio pair programming

Tags: gratis, c++, collaboration, visual-studio

There are many plugins for other editors that allow for two people to work on a project together in real-time. For example, Saros (for Eclipse), Floobits (for many) and many for Atom.

Is there anything like this for Visual Studio?

I've already seen VS Anywhere, which is paid, really expensive and dead, and Collab, which isn't released for some reason. I need a free one.

Comment: Are you sure you understood pair programming correctly? Pair programming is not 2 developers coding in parallel on one PC. The idea behind it is to have one developer implement and the other just watching him, asking questions, making suggestions etc. so they'll both learn from each other.

Comment: I'm talking about *remote distributed pair programming*, if it isn't clear enough.
BTW, I gave examples, go check 'em out.